# ps_mem.py vs top - memory usage?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, memory, top

Every now and again my apache server is crashing, getting an error saying the MaxClients has been reached. In my research I've gained the impression that I may be running out of memory (just checked and MaxClients is set to 1500, though number of apache processes hovers between 40 and 100)

Anyway that's just a bit of background.

When I run `top` I am told I've about 15GB in total, 14GB in used and the Free seems at the moment to be hovering between 500MB - 1GB (though about an hour earlier it was about 3-4 GB free)

I have also run `ps_mem.py` however and that shows only 3-4 GB being used!

Why the difference? And which one is correct?

Comment: What do tools like `free` and `vmstat` report? Are you counting buffer space? What linux kernel version?

Comment: `free` and `vmstat` are similar to `top`.  Kernel: 3.2.0-72-virtual

Comment: Right Now:
`top` / `free` - Buffers - 2.5GB, Cached - 5.8GB - Free 300MB - 15GB total
`ps_mem.sy` - 2.5GB

Answer (score 0):

`ps_mem.py` is IMO bit more precise because it [assesses amount of shared memory correct where top is buggy.](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/TopSharedMemoryBug)

top reads `/proc/<PID>/statm` whereas ps_mem.py reads more detailed info from `/proc/<PID>/smaps` and assesses total usage of multi-processing daemon with more precision.

For details I recommend reading [through `ps_mem.py` code](https://github.com/pixelb/ps_mem/blob/master/ps_mem.py#L214-L251)

Comment: why the downvote?